# Firebase write permission denied

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I can't figure out why firebase won't let me do this specific write. I feel like I do it the same in the simulator and it works there. Below are my security rules for this section.

```
"joinRequests" : {
  "$clanid": {
    "$requesterid" : {
      ".read" : "$requesterid === auth.uid || root.child('clans/' + $clanid + '/members/' + auth.uid + '/admin').val() === true",
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['request'])",
      "request" : {
        ".write" : "true",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'message'])",
        "name" : {
        ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "message" : {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },
        "$other": {
        ".validate": false
        }
      },
      "approved" : {
        ".write" : "root.child('clans/' + $clanid + '/members/' + auth.uid + '/admin').val() === true || ($requesterid === auth.uid  && !newData.exists())",
        ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
      },
      "$other": {
      ".validate": false
      }
    }
  }
},
```

In the code for my android app I run these two lines:

```
dataSnapshot.child("request").getRef().removeValue();
dataSnapshot.child("approved").getRef().removeValue();
```

What I find weird is that it allows me to remove the "approved" value but not the "request" value. The dataSnapshot is a $requesterid. If I run this line in the simulator and it allows the write:

```
/joinRequests/QV28VJYG/c1cef959-2dd3-4cab-8649-2b81892cffa6/request
```

The error I get in android studio is this:

```
W/RepoOperation: setValue at /joinRequests/QV28VJYG/qRlJt4UIAcRVIe9VXoYVBa68tO43/request failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

It must be something dumb that I'm doing but I can't imagine what it would be. Any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Can you try it without this validate rule inside the request: ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'message'])",?

Comment: So it turns out the problem was with this line ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['request'])" because of my requirements I couldn't put the allow write on the $requesterid so I was trying to just delete the children and it was this rule in the parent that was not allowing it. Weird that the simulator wouldn't catch it though.

Comment: Wooooops. Yep it looks like the simulator UI was expecting sorted line messages and fails to highlight some lines when the API returns an unsorted array of line messages. I'll fix it. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**newData** is a snapshot that represent how data will look like after the operation took place.

`newData.hasChildren(['request'])` tells firebase to make sure that the `request` node exists after the operation was executed. Therefore, deletion of this node is prohibited.